# CSS Centering a webpage problem

Tags: html, css

I've trouble centering my webpage using the css:

CSS code below:

```
#wrapper {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width: 100px;
}

#welcome {
    position:absolute;
    top:202px;
    width:560px;
    height:224px;
    z-index:2;
}
#newsSection {
    position:absolute;
    left:576px;
    top:209px;
    width:380px;
    height:600px;
    z-index:2;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="welcome">
    //content here
 </div>
 <div id="newsSection">
    //content here
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I can center the webpage except for the #newsSection div.

The reason why I put "left:576px" under #newsSection div is because I want it to place it right next to the #welcome div.(side by side)  However, when I shrink my browser size, #newsSection div will move to the left a bit and overlap #welcome div.
If I remove "left:57px", then the #newsSection div will appear right on top of #welcome div...

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because youre using absolute position on the child divs. Therefore, "the kids will run wild", as in, they don't care that the parent div#wrapper is center.

Some potential code:

```
#wrapper {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width: 100px;
}

#welcome {
    float: left;
    width:560px;
    height:224px;
}
#newsSection {
    float: left;
    width:380px;
    height:600px;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I remove the aboslute position. Right now, everything is in the center, good BUT, #newsSection div appear BELOW #welcome div. I want it to appear next to it.  How can I do it?

Comment: just added some potential code (not exactly sure how you want it to appear, but this'd be my best guess.

Comment: Good to hear. And as a tip to help out others with similar problems, you should mark this post as the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score -1):

you should use relative positioning, ie, tagname.class {position:relative; top/right:? ;}

Answer (score -2):

To center a webpage you can use this:

```html
.container{
   width: 100%;
   max-width:80%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: `width: 100%; max-width:80%;` is nonsense. You might as well just set `width: 80%`.